# How to connect to home NAS while on home network and at the same time - on corporate VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, nas

When I work from home, I usually have to connect to a corporate VPN (with Cisco AnyConnect client app).

I was wondering if there is a way to figure out how to access my home NAS without disconnecting from work VPN – not through the web, but through the home network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up Anyconnect for Split Tunneling and then you can use your local resources (NAS) while the VPN is connected.

[Split Tunnel on Anyconnect](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/119006-configure-anyconnect-00.htmlhttps://)

> Split tunnelling is a feature that you can use in order to define the
> traffic for the subnets or hosts that must be encrypted. This involves
> the configuration of an Access Control List (ACL) that will be
> associated with this feature. The traffic for the subnets or hosts
> that is defined on this ACL will be encrypted over the tunnel from the
> client-end, and the routes for these subnets are installed on the PC
> routing table.
>
> Complete these steps in order to move from the Tunnel-all
> configuration to the Split-tunnel configuration:
>
> Navigate to Configuration > Remote Access VPN > Group Policies:
>
> Click Edit, and use the navigation tree in order to navigate to
> Advanced > Split Tunneling. Uncheck the Inherit check box in the
> Policy section, and select Tunnel Network List Below from the drop
> down menu:
>
> Uncheck the Inherit check box in the Network List section, and click
> Manage in order to select the ACL that specifies the LAN network(s) to
> which the client needs access:
>
> Click Standard ACL, Add, Add ACL, and then ACL name:
>
> Click Add ACE in order to add the rule:
>
> Click Apply.
>
> Once connected, the routes for the subnets or hosts on the split ACL
> are added to the routing table of the client machine.